# How to create a Windows Service in Python?

Tags: c++, python, windows, windows-services

What is the today's most working and nice way to create a Windows Service using Python 2.7 (or Python 3) that is working in Win XP and Win 7? How to create an installer for it that would work on WinXP, Win7? Also, what is the common way to auto-update such a service? Can it download new version and restart itself?

Is there some troubles special for Python-based services that is much easier to solve using C++ instead of Python?

I need to implement a simple windows service which will send 1 HTTP request per hour and analyze a response.

Trying to understand what way is the best in terms of service stability, development speed and compatibility with different versions of windows: WinXP, Win7 (,win8?): using C++/visual studio/CURL or using Python? I feel myself more experienced with C++, but implementing HTTP code and service's logic is easier in Python.

Comment: see my answer below, it should do the trick

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692921/windows-services-with-python-and-py2exe/21914550#21914550

Comment: You have asked several non-trivial questions. Please pick just one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this procedure

```
sc create "[YourService]" binPath= "C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\srvany.exe"
```

Now, run regedit. In the Registry Editor dialog select

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SYSTEM > CurrentControlSet > Services > [YourService]
```

Now, run regedit. In the Registry Editor dialog select

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SYSTEM > CurrentControlSet > Services > [YourService]
```

With `[YourService]` selected, hit `Edit > New > Key` from the toolbar.

Type Parameters and hit enter.

From the toolbar select `Edit > New > String Value`.

Type Application and hit enter.

Right-click Application and select Modify.

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:\[YourServicePath].py
```

Hit the OK button.

Your new service is created.

Comment: This is a tutorial about starting python code as a service on my machine. But i would like to have an installer that would deploy a service on any winXP, Win7 machine.

Comment: what is the difference in this procedure and just "python servicepathname.py install". should the latter do the same as former.